# Is it possible to integrate my existing Firebase project(iOS and Android) to separate google analytic account without losing current data

Tags: android, ios, firebase, google-analytics

I have a Firebase project already setup for iOS and Android platforms. Now I want to integrate with Google analytic account not from the same firebase account I am using but the other separate account where we have already integrated web.
Is it possible to do that? if yes how can I setup new google analytics for my existing project? and how it will work?
Appreciate the feedback

Comment: To Me, No you can't because of "GoogleService-Info.plist" that it is unique for each Account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't because of "**GoogleService-Info.plist**" it is unique for each Account.